# Convert from LPWSTR to LPTSTR

Tags: c++

Im trying to convert arguments LPWSTR to LPTSTR, it there any library I can user for easy string convertion?

Comment: that is ofc the first place i look, and iv been looking around for a long time, cant find any good awnsers to this...

Comment: Look here it has some good info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus: this can't really be googled. there are pat answers to be found (including below), but they're mostly all wrong or wrongheaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `_UNICODE` is defined there's no conversion to do - a `TCHAR`  is a `WCHAR`, and `LPWSTR` is `LPTSTR`; otherwise, `TCHAR` is a `CHAR`, and `LPTSTR` is `LPSTR`. In this last case, you can use the [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to convert a `LPWSTR` (i.e. a Unicode string) to a "narrow" string.

Also, you can use the `wcstombs` C library function, assuming that the Windows types `CHAR` and `WCHAR` map to the C types `char` and `wchar_t` (which is surely the case in VC++), and that the current C locale is the one you intend to use for the conversion.

---

See also *Alf*'s comments for more insight on the matter - the most important point being that *if you can you should avoid such conversion*, since your output encoding in general cannot represent faithfully the input, and, depending from what your string represents this may mean garbled text as well as not finding the required file or, even worse, operating on the wrong path.

So, set your project to use Unicode (as in *@prazuber*'s answer) and always try to use Unicode-aware APIs, so to avoid this kind of conversion.

Still, keep in mind that using only the Unicode version of the Windows APIs may mean losing compatibility with Windows 9x; this is not a problem for the vast majority of cases, but if it's critical to support such OSes in your application check if the APIs you are using are supported in [MSLU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688166.aspx).

Comment: well, it's both far easier and far more complicated than your answer indicates. first the complication: if the wide string is a path, and `LPTSTR` is a narrow string, and the recipient uses it to open a file or directory, and conversion must be done, then a bit more than simple encoding conversion is needed, because the *information content should then be preserved* (what the path refers to) . one solution is to convert to short path if necessary. regarding the simple solution, it is (when applicable): *to not support MFC DLLs in Windows 9x*, which means, no need to use the silly `T` stuff.

Comment: readers should also note that `wcstombs` is an all-or-nothing thing: if there is just one byte it doesn't like, then it fails completely. so it's not an alternative to `WideCharToMultiByte`. it has different semantics, for different needs.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: correct, and in general the situation about paths is particularly dangerous, since your application potentially have to deal with Unicode paths that cannot be represented in the current CP (also, the default `?` replacement character can be problematic in paths). So, the best solution to this problem is, as you say, *don't do "narrowing" encoding conversions* and work in some Unicode format internally. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

LPTSTR is defined as follows:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
 typedef LPWSTR LPTSTR;
#else
 typedef LPSTR LPTSTR;
#endif
```

So all you need to do is switch your character set to Unicode. For example, in Visual Studio you go to *Configuration Properties* -> *General* -> *Character Set* -> *Use Unicode Character Set*.